# bash is trying to execute my variable name, wth

Tags: git, bash, github

I have this script which I am writing to help my team squash Git commits into the integration branch on the remote. Needless to say my bash scripting is a bit wanting.

First, here is the script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash

    FEATURE_BRANCH_NAME="$1" &&


    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
      echo "You did not specify a branch name."
      exit 1;
    fi

    if [${1} == "--force"]; then     # the problem seems to happen here!
      echo "You did not specify a branch name."
      exit 1;
    fi

    if [ "$2" != "--force" ]; then
      echo "Are you sure you want to squash commits for branch name = $FEATURE_BRANCH_NAME? If so use --force."
      exit 1;
    fi



    git fetch origin &&
    git checkout -b temp_branch origin/integration &&
    git merge -Xtheirs --squash -m "squashed with branch=$FEATURE_BRANCH_NAME" $FEATURE_BRANCH_NAME &&
    git checkout $FEATURE_BRANCH_NAME &&
    git merge temp_branch &&
    git push origin $FEATURE_BRANCH_NAME


    #end
```

The problem I am seeing is that if I execute the above script like so:

```
./script.sh $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

then bash tries to actually execute the command represented by the value of `$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)`, (which is the current branch name).

So in other words, if the output of `$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) is "xyz_branch"`, then bash will try to run $ xyz_branch, and bash will spit out:

```
[xyz_branch: command not found
```

Above the in script there is a comment # which specifies which line this happening on. What the heck is going on?

Comment: You're missing a space between `[` and `${1}`.

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend.

Comment: ...in terms of how to think about it: `[` is a **command**. There's actually a `/usr/bin/[` (or `/bin/[`, depending on your OS) on-disk, though most shells also provide a built-in version for performance reasons as well. As such, like any other command, you need spaces between the command name and its arguments. You can't run `lsmydir/` instead of `ls mydir/`; the same is true of `[`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy awesome tool!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are missing a space here:

```
if [ ${1} == "--force" ];
    ^                 ^ (second error)
```

Also, you probably mean to use `=` instead of `==`.

---

The `if` construct in bash has a syntax like this:

```
if command; ...
```

And the result of `command` tells `if` whether to execute the if or the else part. Now `[` is another command (otherwise known as `test`).

So, in bash, if you write:

```
$ [ a = b ]
```

This is actually the program `[` called with arguments `a`, `=`, `b` and `]` (the program could be internally handled by bash, even if you actually have an executable named `[`)

Looking back at your problem, you are trying to execute:

```
$ [${1} == "--force"]
```

which is the program `[${1}` with parameters `==` and `--force]`. Clearly not what you want!

---

A couple of other things to bare in mind here. First, it's a good idea to quote `"${1}"` because if it has spaces or is empty, as you might imagine it would create an incorrect list of arguments to `[`.

Another is that you don't have to always use `[` in the context of an `if`, `while` etc. You can for example take advantage of the C-like short-circuit property of logical operations:

```
$ [ "$a" = "$b" ] && echo My variables are equal
```

Comment: Also at the end before the `]`.

Comment: And please quote the parameter expansion .

Comment: (Aside: You're entirely right to suggest using `=` rather than `==`, since `==` is a bash/ksh extension and not guaranteed to be portable, whereas `=` is POSIX-defined. Thank you for pointing that out -- it's an item far too many people ignore).